# GWT, addStyleNames not adding second style from CssResource

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to add a second style to a GWT g:label. I have the CSS styles defined as a CssResource. The label is picking up .gwt-Label style fine, but it is not picking up the change of font colour defined in the added style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
 xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

 <ui:with field='res' type='com.me.area.workflow.portal.flip.client.ui.Resources' />

    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PCT'>
        <g:west size="50">
          <g:Label addStyleNames="{.navPanelText}">Flip Workflows</g:Label>
        </g:west>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

and CSS

```
.gwt-Label {
   font: bold 16px "Lucida Grande", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
 }

 .navPanelText {
   color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<g:Label addStyleNames="{.navPanelText}">Flip Workflows</g:Label>
```

To:

```
<g:Label addStyleNames="{res.style.navPanelText}">Flip Workflows</g:Label>
```

This is assuming that you did all of the other stuff you need to do right. Such as the 'Resources'' ClientBundle' has a 'CssResource' named 'style()'. Which is properly linked to the right CSS style sheet.

Without `res.style` you're not referencing your style sheet and you're simply inserting `{.navPanelText}` as a style.

Even though the name of your class is `.navPanelText` in your CSS GWT changes the names of the classes. In order to keep the reference to that class name you need to reference the style sheet's corresponding Java file and style name through the method called the same as the class name.

For more information go [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html).

You could also simply just put the CSS directly in UiBinder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
 xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <ui:style>
        .navPanelText {
            color: white;
        }
    </ui:style>

    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PCT'>
        <g:west size="50">
          <g:Label addStyleNames="{style.navPanelText}">Flip Workflows</g:Label>
        </g:west>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
 </ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: It should actually be `{res.style.navPanelText}`, assuming the `Resources`  `ClientBundle` has a `CssResource`named `style()`.

Comment: That's right I just edited the post. Thanks Thomas. I am making a lot of assumptions in the answer. If you don't understand ClientBundles you should really [read up](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) on them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. The doc page you pointed me at doesn't have an example of using CssResouce from UiBinder. I want to externalise the css for obvious reasons.

Comment: If you want to externalize you have no choice but to use the first method but it's easy to do once you understand what you're doing. Just a bit more overhead than wanted if it's just for a few styles.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html provides details of using res.styles ... found it now I know what I was looking for.

Comment: @RichardGeorge `<ui:with>` just does a `GWT.create()` of the class (unless `@UiField(provided=true)` in Java, or with a `@UiFactory` or `@UiConstructor`), and puts it in a _variable_, then then `{}` notation just calls methods, such that `{res.style.navPanelText}` maps to `res.style().navPanelText()`. `<ui:style>` creates an implicit `CssResource` in an implicit `ClientBundle`, with methods derived from class names used in the stylesheet, and puts it in a `style` variable (by default, you can use a `field` attribute to change it), then the `{}` works the same.